# Is it possible to have a PhD advisor from another university?

Tags: phd, advisor

I am a graduate student, 2nd year, in a STEM field at a US university. I have passed my quals.

Is it possible to ask from a Professor who is not at your university to be your advisor?  Did anybody hear of a similar situation?

I am very interested in the research of a professor who is at a nearby university, I really want to work with him but I don't know if this is even possible. (Maybe I should also note that his university is not necessarily better than the one I am now.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extrapolating from the very few cases that I've seen, I think you'll need an official adviser at the school where you're actually enrolled.  If it's OK with that adviser, then you could also have a "real" adviser elsewhere, on an unofficial basis.  Your school may have some paperwork to be completed if your real adviser is to serve as a member of your official thesis committee.

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard of that except in the case where a prof left one university to go to another. During the long transition, some of his students physically moved with him but continued their PhD at the old school. I believe the professor retained some sort of appointment at the old university in order to make it fit within the University's rules.

That being said, almost every PhD committee is required to have an external member. That's usually outside the department, but it is often outside the university. So, it might be possible to find an advisor at your current university to be the nominal head of your committee, but to include the other guy on the committee and have him be the de facto head. The biggest problem will probably come down to how your research is funded. If funding is not a problem, then you might be able to pull it off.

Comment: I know a few examples of this happening in math, though it may be even rarer in other fields.

Comment: Not that rare, professors do occasionally change universities and that will often impact any students that  they are advising.

Comment: This actually happens on a regular basis between the math departments of Harvard and MIT, in both directions.  Harvard has no combinatorics, for example, so interested students end up working with Stanley (typically, or Postnikov) at MIT.  And my advisor, Gaitsgory, had a student at MIT.

Comment: Glad to know there are more reasons for this to happen than I was aware of.